# How to replace a zero with a frequent value in a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to learn more about csv maliputation in python and created a csv file. What I'm trying to figure out is how to replace a zero value with a value before it.

[image: The code here is what I done so far]

[image: The image here shows one of the zeros I want to replace. The zero should be replaced 30.969999]

Comment: I'd recommend looking into the pandas package for python. Especially for these kinds of tasks there are many many functions that will do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in `csv` module no matter what, then you can do it by just adding a few lines to your `if-else` statement. Just add:

```py
for row in range(len(reader)):
    for i in range(len(reader[row])):
        if (reader[row][i] == '0'):
            if i: #Check if there's a number before the occurrence of 0
                reader[row][i] = reader[row][i-1]
            else: 
                pass
```

Otherwise, if you aren't really particular with your module, then try using `pandas`, which is a much more powerful package than the `csv` package.

Comment: I was going to answer the same; you should also add a check that we're not already on the first element, because if i == 0, we'd end at [-1], and that's not what we want...

Comment: I know, that's what the `if i:` statement is. If `i` is anything other than zero, it will return True.

Comment: ops, I was looking for it... and still missed it, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this should work, if you are willing to install pandas

(pip install pandas)

```
import pandas as pd

D = pd.read_csv("Stock....")
D = D[["desiredColumn"]].replace(0, pd.np.nan )
D = D[["desiredColumn"]].fillna(method="ffill")
```

In this example all zeros are first replaced with NAN. Once this is done you can use the fillna function that will fill all NAN. This function has a convinience function to either forward fill (`ffill`) or backward fill (`bfill`) all NANs

Comment: The person wants to replace a zero value with the value before it. That's the question. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something specific to csv's. You can do it easily as below.

```
import csv

with open("input.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        res = []  # load this list with the sanitized `values`
        for v in row:
            res.append(v if float(v) else res[-1])  # important! first element of `row` must be non-zero
        print(res)  # use `res` instead of `row`
```

As noted, this assumes each `row` starts with a non-zero value.

If this is not guaranteed, a simple solution would be initializing `res` list with a fallback value for starting zeros then discard the first element of the `res` once it is loaded.

I.e.

```
import csv

with open("input.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        res = [99]  # if first value of `row` is zero, consider it as `99`
        for v in row:
            res.append(v if float(v) else res[-1])  # important! first element of r must be non-zero
        res = res[1:]  # discard the first element after `res` is loaded
        print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should transfer the data to its own data structure. The default choice would be a list, unless you want to use it with a library that needs something else input.

```
import csv

values = list()
with open('file.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)

    for row in reader:
        value = int(row[1])
        if value == 0:
            if values:
                values.append( values[-1] )
            else:
                # Whatever is meaningful in this case
                pass
        else:
            values.append( value )

# do stuff with values here
```

PS: You make answerers' lives easier if you paste your code as code and not as a screenshot of code. This might make the difference of getting an answer or not in one of your future questions.

Comment: `int(row[1])` will crash if `row[1]` is a string representing a floating point. e.g. `1.234`